# Picture absent after updating the constraints in swift 3 on iPhone 5 screen

Tags: swift, constraints

I am facing an issue with my pictures which I should display on my iPhone app. Everything is working perfectly on iPhone 6/6Plus 7/7Plus, but when I test it on iPhone 5/5s they disappear. Please look at the pictures below:

Iphone 5

[image]

Iphone 6
[image]

There aren't any problems with missing constraints, so I don't know what to do now.Would you please advice me?

P.S. the flags are inside the buttons, the UIImage is placed over the UIButton)

Comment: Check your button's view bounds' width. Seems like it's clipping it's contents.

Comment: How can I check that? I am beginner, sorry if it is stupid.

Comment: [Debugging View Hierarchies](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it by adding the width and height constraints. 
Example : 50px x 50px.
In this case, the size of the buttons is fixed on every iPhone screen. Now works perfectly even on iPhone 5 and all other devices.